# Uiimageview animation is not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

Im using the following code to center an image within a view

```
 UIImage* img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.gif"];
UIImage* img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"];
UIImage* img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.gif"];
UIImage* img4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.gif"];



UIView *loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/4, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 170, 170)];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 40, loadingView.bounds.size.width, loadingView.bounds.size.height)];
loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
loadingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
loadingView.center = self.view.center;
imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imgView.center = loadingView.center;
imgView.animationImages = @[img1, img2, img3, img4];
imgView.animationDuration = 1.0*1.0;
[loadingView addSubview: imgView];
[self.view addSubview:loadingView];
[imgView startAnimating];
```

1. I have defined four uiimages initially
2. I have defined the loadingview and I have centered it to the screen
3. I have defined an imageview and i have centered it to the loading view.
4. I have added the imageview to be the subview of  loadingView and I have added the loading view to the view.Then im animating the imageview

The problem is that the imaeview is not being shown when i run this code. How can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: I think your `frame` is incorrect, because other code is correct, due to wrong frame it is not visible, try to debug that.

Comment: imgView.center = loadingView.center; is incorrect and for proper animation with this code you need to break the images to separate png/jpeg files .

Comment: use  SDWebImage to set gif image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Here is the code

```
UIImage* img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.gif"];
UIImage* img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"];

UIView *loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/4, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 170, 170)];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 170)];
loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
loadingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
loadingView.center = self.view.center;
imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imgView.animationImages = @[img1, img2];
imgView.animationDuration = 1.0*1.0;
[loadingView addSubview: imgView];
[imgView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:loadingView];
```

Comment: You should try to explain what changes have you done along with the reason if possible.